# A girl with ginger hair is reincarnated into a novel that I think was called "Hestia's Men"

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

It's a manhwa or manga where she reincarnates into a novel called *Hestia's Men* as the Female Lead's best friend. In the original novel, she gets sold off when her family becomes poor, so she wants to be a knight or something, to not get sold off as a bride. I think she also makes magical objects and sells them for money, and can use magic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the name of any of the characters or places in the story?

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[I Don't Want to Be an Ojakgyo](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-dont-want-to-be-an-ojakgyo)***...?

> **I was reincarnated as a supporting character in a novel. And on top of that, I had the role of a ‘magpie bridge’ inside the romance story <Hestia’s Boys>.** Anyways, romance was impossible, and my future seemed bleak with my debt-riddled family. After becoming a civil servant, I tried to enjoy the wealth and honor I couldn’t have in my past life, but… Unlike the originals, the male characters seem kind of strange?! “Imagine, how would Char-Char look blushing and shy while looking at someone she likes?” “Wow….. that’d be amazing.” Keurigord gets blank-stared, Hylli wants to talk whenever we see each other, and Yves wears an expression and mutters to himself. “Should I take you and run away….” Sean would cover his face with both hands without saying anything. His blush used to only reach his face but now the red spreads to the tip of his ears. Why are you guys not obsessing over the female lead and doing other stuff instead? Charine West, who wanted to live a normal life, and her survival at Char-Char’s reverse harem.

A Korean woman is reincarnated in the world of a novel titled "Hestia's Boys" as Schulaina West, the orange-haired daughter of a baron and the best friend of Hestia Flawid, the female lead of the novel.

> [image: "I Don't Want to Be an Ojakgyo," chapter 1, page 11.]

In the original plot of the novel, Schulaina's family goes bankrupt and she's sold off as a bride, so to avoid that fate, she studies swordsmanship at an academy, with the intention of becoming a knight, viewing that as a path to financial security.

She also secretly lives a double life as 'Schneeballen,' a mysterious engineer who earns money by fixing the underworld's magical devices. She wears a magic cloak in this identity and carries a satchel containing a magic crystal that functions as a voice transmitter, and a magic ball she made that functions like a [Poké Ball](https://nintendo.fandom.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball).

> [image: "I Don't Want to Be an Ojakgyo," chapter 5, page 85, 86, 87, 88 and 89.]