# A girl gets reincarnated as the villain’s sister and she gets engaged to a fat heir to a dukedom because her sister didn’t want to marry him

Tags: story-identification, reincarnation

She reincarnated as the villain’s sister in a novel she read and I think she was blond.  She gets engaged to a fat heir to a dukedom (I think?) and she gives him a solution to lose some weight. At a party she meets the crown prince (I think?) and says something the ogfl says and he gets interested in her and I think that later he falls in love with her.

Comment: Just to be clear, her sister is the villain?

Comment: @purple lotus - Was your [previous story-ID question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/280650/a-girl-with-ginger-hair-is-reincarnated-into-a-novel-that-i-think-was-called-he/280652#280652) answered correctly? if it was, please consider marking that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

[Even though I become a side character, I’m being adored by an overprotective duke](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/z5gdbft/mob-na-no-ni-kahogo-na-koushaku-ni-dekiaisareteimasu):

> I've been transmigrated as "Leticia," a mob character from an otome game. I was forced to take Lionel as my fiancé by my twin sister (who, by the way, has the worst personality). The first time I met Lionel, he was nothing but chubby and fat, just as the rumours said he'd be… However, me being me, I realised that Lionel is an unpolished gem with potential to shine, so I decided to re-invent him. Even if I'm a mob character, my days of doting on my fiancé began when my fiancé transformed both inside and out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide more details about this so it's clear how it matches?