# Manhwa about a young girl who is reborn with reddish orange hair in a romance harem game as the female lead's best friend

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, sword-and-sorcery

The manhwa starts out with a girl in a cloak chasing a boy and yelling for him to stop and calling him a thief. She was getting tired of running and was going to be late for her first day of school. After an intense chase, she catches up to the boy who has black hair and red eyes. She was chasing him because they both bought the same sword, but he grabbed it first. After arguing with him, she uses a magic capsule to capture him and he promised to give her the sword if she let him out. After she let him out, he ran away telling her that she should never come near him again or else she was dead, and she too had to hurry before she was late for school.

It then showed that she was in a romance game she had played in her past life as the female lead's (FL's) best friend. It then shows a cover that has the FL with silver hair surrounded by guys, one with black hair and red eyes and the other with orange hair with purple eyes and glasses, plus two other guys I can't remember. At school, she realizes that the boy she ran into earlier was the crown prince (one of the love interests) and they are both in the same major of swords. Her friend, the FL of the game, is so beautiful that all the boys want to court her and they would try to use the protagonist to get to her, but she was having none of it. When the FL would be asked about her ideal man, she would say a nick name for the protagonist, something like 'roro' or along those lines.

The protagonist is the only girl in the fencing classes and is better than majority of them, because she uses her magic abilities to her advantage. After some blackmail, she and the prince become training partners and eventually friends and later she becomes friend with his roommate, another one of the FL's love interests (the one with orange hair and glasses), and she convinces him to join her club of magic.

After a while, exams come along and she and the boys go to a forest and end up capturing a slime, which was later used for her magic club's project, and as a thanks she gives the orange-haired boy a magic earring she made and he realizes that she is a famous underground magic item maker with a street name along the lines of '$keball' that he idolized.

When on break, they made sure that they would keep in contact with each other and hang out.  hen the protagonist and her brother get home, she checks in on her other younger brother about their mother's spending, because she spends all the family's money on things and will run them into poverty, so she confronts her and plays to her motherly instincts to get her to stop. The protagonist ended up getting a deal she couldn't refuse and met a boy from her school with long orange hair who needed her help, and in they end, they ended up undercover in a bar where she made a distraction and that is where I left off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[I Don't Want to Be an Ojakgyo](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-dont-want-to-be-an-ojakgyo)***...?

> **I was reincarnated as a supporting character in a novel. And on top of that, I had the role of a ‘magpie bridge’ inside the romance story <Hestia’s Boys>.** Anyways, romance was impossible, and my future seemed bleak with my debt-riddled family. After becoming a civil servant, I tried to enjoy the wealth and honor I couldn’t have in my past life, but… Unlike the originals, the male characters seem kind of strange?! “Imagine, how would Char-Char look blushing and shy while looking at someone she likes?” “Wow….. that’d be amazing.” Keurigord gets blank-stared, Hylli wants to talk whenever we see each other, and Yves wears an expression and mutters to himself. “Should I take you and run away….” Sean would cover his face with both hands without saying anything. His blush used to only reach his face but now the red spreads to the tip of his ears. Why are you guys not obsessing over the female lead and doing other stuff instead? Charine West, who wanted to live a normal life, and her survival at Char-Char’s reverse harem.

A Korean woman is reincarnated in the world of a novel (not a game) titled "Hestia's Boys" as Schulaina West, the orange-haired daughter of a baron and the best friend of Hestia Flawid, the female lead of the novel, who has multiple male admirers.

> [image: "I Don't Want to Be an Ojakgyo," chapter 1, page 11.]

In the original plot of the novel, Schulaina's family goes bankrupt and she's sold off as a bride, so to avoid that fate, she studies swordsmanship at an academy, with the intention of becoming a knight, viewing that as a path to financial security.

She also secretly lives a double life as 'Schneeballen,' a mysterious engineer who earns money by fixing the underworld's magical devices. She wears a magic cloak in this identity and carries a satchel containing a magic crystal that functions as a voice transmitter, and a magic ball she made that functions like a [Poké Ball](https://nintendo.fandom.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball).

> [image: "I Don't Want to Be an Ojakgyo," chapter 5, page 85, 86, 87, 88 and 89.]

I haven't read as far into the manhwa as you have, but it starts just as you described, with Schulaina chasing the black-haired crown prince while in her 'Schneeballen' disguise, and using her magic ball to capture him in order to get a sword from him.

After that, she takes off her magic cloak, switches back to her normal identity and attends an entrance ceremony at her new school, where she ends up meeting the prince again, who's taking the same swordsmanship class as her, but doesn't recognise her in this identity.

Comment: Unaccepted answer (provided by you) [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/280650/a-girl-with-ginger-hair-is-reincarnated-into-a-novel-that-i-think-was-called-he).